# How to call the main activity of library from cordova project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I added a native library into a cordova project and now i want to open main activity of library project with on click in my JS file of Cordova project.

How can I call the main activity of library from cordova project?

Comment: Why do you want to call that? main activity is already opened when you launch your app.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @VicJordan I want to add an app inside the another app So, thats why i make an app into a library than add it to my cordova project

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the native activity from cordova project,you need to make an activity in native side which extends CordovaPlugin class.Then you need to specify the cordova plugin in config.xml file in the following format

`<feature name="name of plugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="path" />
    </feature>`.

After this call the plugin from JS using `cordova.exec()` method. Please refer the official cordova plugin documentation for more details